# Serverless Framework: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless

When trying to deploy my application with Serverless Framework using the properties:

```
package:
  individually: true
```

i got the follow error:

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

My NodeJS version is 10.*.*

Answer (score 0):

Some people said to enhance the NodeJS memory with the code:

```
export NODE_OPTIONS="--max-old-space-size=8192"
```

But i had no happy result.

I just ended up this error installing a newer version of NodeJS. In my case v14.15.4